# Excel: copy entire row and contents but change cell reference?

Tags: excel, formula

I am using the following code to copy a row in excel and all of its contents when a user clicks on a certain cell in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Target.Row > 150 And Target.Column = Range("A1").Column Then
  On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveCell
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .EntireRow.Insert
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End If
```

this copies the row above and all of its contents, however In the cell in column B, I have a formula like so

```
='[NewSupplierSet-Up.xls]New Supplier Set-Up'!$B17
```

what I want is for the cell reference in this formula to increment by 1 each time the row is copied? so that the next row will be

```
='[NewSupplierSet-Up.xls]New Supplier Set-Up'!$B18
```

can someone please show me if there is a way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Copied row may be inserted **below** the active cell.

```
With ActiveCell
    .EntireRow.Copy
    .EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
End with
```

Then the cell references inside formulas would **increment**.